# Сделать запись в публичный файл в React

Tags: reactjs

В package.json есть поле с версией приложения.
Нужно что бы эта версия записывалась в файлик(txt или json) в папке public (что бы данные о версии можно было посмотреть по прямому адресу, например myapp.com/version.json, и использовать в других проектах)
Можно ли это как то реализовать, именно что бы данная версия записывалась автоматом из package.json?